# What is the correct way to include external vendor plugins (that are not gems) in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a few external code bases I want to include in my Rails 4 app which are not gems.

Specifically projects like https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI

I want to be able to download the project into /vendor and then refer to any included stylesheets by referencing the project folder.

```
vendor/flat-ui/css
vendor/flat-ui/js
```

This way I can easily pull down the latest version of the repo when I want to and have my code point to that.

Is it possible to reference projects placed within /vendor?

Or am I stuck having to copy files individually to /vendor/assets/stylesheets and /vendor/assets/javascript before I can work with them?